# Carregar barra de progresso conforme a importação C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, progress-bar

Como fazer a barra de progresso carregar conforme a importação do arquivo excel estiver em andamento ?

Meu código até agora:

ASPX:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload" runat="server" Style="margin-top: 4px" /><br />
    <div id="progressbar" style="width:550px;">
       <label id="label" text="0%"></label>
    </div>
<asp:Label ID="label2" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Function:

```
function updateProgress() {
    //var value = $("#progressbar").progressbar("option", "value");
    if (value < 100) {
        $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", value + 1);
        document.getElementById("label").innerHTML = value + 1 + '%';
        $("#<%=label2.ClientID%>").text("Processando...");
    }
}

$("#<%=btnProcessar.ClientID%>").click(function () {
    var intervalID = setInterval(updateProgress, 100);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ConciliacaoPedidos.aspx/GetText",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        async: true,
        success: function(msg) {
            $("#progressbar").progressbar("value", 100);
            $("#<%=label2.ClientID%>").text("");
            $("#result").text(msg.d);
            clearInterval(intervalID);
        }
    });
});
```

Método .cs:

```
public void ImportarArquivoExcel(string FilePath)
{
    this.conexaoExcel(FilePath);
    this.excelConn.Open();

    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
    cmd.Connection = excelConn;

    DataTable dtSheetnames = excelConn.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();

    foreach (DataRow dr in dtSheetnames.Rows)
    {
        string sheetName = dr["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();

        if (!sheetName.EndsWith("$"))
        {
            continue;
        }

        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();

        query.Append("AQUI EU MONTO A QUERY DO EXCEL")

        cmd.CommandText = query.ToString();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        dt.TableName = sheetName;

        OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
        oda.Fill(dt);

        DataTable dtExcel = dt.Clone();

        dtExcel.Columns[0].DataType = typeof(string);
        dtExcel.Columns[1].DataType = typeof(double);
        dtExcel.Columns[2].DataType = typeof(int);
        dtExcel.Columns[3].DataType = typeof(double);
        dtExcel.Columns[4].DataType = typeof(int);
        dtExcel.Columns[5].DataType = typeof(decimal);
        dtExcel.Columns[6].DataType = typeof(decimal);

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            dtExcel.ImportRow(row);
        }

        dt.Clear();
        ds.Clear();

        ds.Tables.Add(dtExcel);
    }

    excelConn.Close();
    DataTable Exceldt = ds.Tables[0];

    conexaoSQL();

    SqlBulkCopy objbulk = new SqlBulkCopy(sqlConn);

    try
    {
        //Mapeia as colunas de origem "Excel" para as colunas de destino "SQL"    
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("PedConcEmpresa", "Campo1");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("TEXTBOX36", "Campo2");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("TEXTBOX41", "Campo3");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("PRODUCTPK", "Campo4");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("QUANTITY", "Campo5");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("PRODUCTPRICE", "Campo6");
        objbulk.ColumnMappings.Add("TEXTBOX27", "Campo7");

        //Seta a tabela para destino    
        objbulk.DestinationTableName = "dbo.Tabela";

        //Faz a inserção na tabela de destino
        sqlConn.Open();
        objbulk.WriteToServer(Exceldt);
        sqlConn.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        metodos.AnalizarErro(ex.Message, Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath, this.Page, this.GetType());
        mensagens.ExibirMensagem("Erro", mensagens.strMsgErroGenerico, false, this.Page, this.GetType());
    }
    finally
    {
        // CLEAR.
        objbulk.Close();
        objbulk = null;
    }
}
```